# How can I connect two pickers as city-district in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

I have a JSON file like so:

```js
[
  {
    "city": "Adana",
    "plaka": 1,
    "districts": [
      "Aladağ",
      "Ceyhan",
      "Çukurova",
      "Feke",
      "İmamoğlu",
      "Karaisalı",
      "Karataş",
      "Kozan",
      "Pozantı",
      "Saimbeyli",
      "Sarıçam",
      "Seyhan",
      "Tufanbeyli",
      "Yumurtalık",
      "Yüreğir"
    ]
  },
  {
    "city": "Adıyaman",
    "plaka": 2,
    "districts": [
      "Besni",
      "Çelikhan",
      "Gerger",
      "Gölbaşı",
      "Kahta",
      "Merkez",
      "Samsat",
      "Sincik",
      "Tut"
    ]
  }
 ]
```

I want to use this JSON file but I can't connect pickers. Here is my first picker:

```js
<Picker
        selectedValue={this.state.selectedCity}
        onValueChange={(itemValue) => {
            this.setState({ selectedCity: itemValue });
        }}
    >
    {this.props.cities.map(city => {
        return (
            <Picker.Item label={city.city} value={city.city} key={city.plaka} />
        );
    })}
</Picker>
```

`city` is my object, `city.city` is my city name by the way.

If I passed city object to `Picker.Item` as a value, picker always shows the "Adana" city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take three variable **selectedCity** is to store the name of the selected city,**selectedCityIndex** is to store the index of selected city and **selectedDistrict** is to store the name of the selected district.

take this in your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedCity: '',
            selectedCityIndex: 0, //by default selected index is 0
            selectedDistrict: '',
        };
    }
```

And in your render method, do the mapping between city and district. Please see below code, It may help you.

```
 render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.selectedCity}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                        this.setState({
                            selectedCity: itemValue,
                            selectedCityIndex: itemIndex
                        });
                    }}
                >
                    {this.state.cities.map(city => {
                        return (
                            <Picker.Item label={city.city} value={city.city} key={city.plaka} />
                        );
                    })}
                </Picker>
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.selectedDistrict}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                        this.setState({
                            selectedDistrict: itemValue,
                        });
                    }}
                >
     //render district list based on selected city
                    {this.props.cities.length > 0 && this.props.cities[this.state.selectedCityIndex].districts.map(district => {
                        return (
                            <Picker.Item label={district} value={district} key={district} />
                        );
                    })}
                </Picker>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what i say. Thank you Thank you Thank you... You made me really happy. :)

Comment: Yeah, Great..! It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.selectedCity.plaka}
    onValueChange={(itemValue) => {
        this.setState({ selectedCity: itemValue });
    }}
>
{this.props.cities.map(city => {
    return (
        <Picker.Item label={city.city} value={city.city} key={city.plaka} />
    );
})}
```